# One to many geospatial search

Tags: mysql, mongodb, geolocation, sphinx, geospatial

For an object I want to associate multiple lat/lng pairs, so that when given my geolocation I can get the object nearest to me [i.e. if any one of those lat/lng pairs satify the nearest condition]

While I know how to do a geospatial search if an object only have one lat/lng pair, I am stuck at this multiple geospatial search.

I am wondering how can achieve this in MySQL, Sphinx, or MongoDB? If there are other technology that can get this done, I would also be grateful to know about that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of locations in MongoDB.

```
> db.array.insert({locs:[ [ 1, 2], [1.5, 1.8], [2, 1] ]})
Inserted 1 record(s) in 134ms
> db.array.ensureIndex({locs:'2d'})
Inserted 1 record(s) in 6ms
> db.array.insert({locs:[ [ 1, 2], [7.5, 1.8], [2, 5] ]})
Inserted 1 record(s) in 2ms
> db.array.find({locs:{$near:[1,2]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a193f11192cab2195f7a8a"), "locs" : [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1.5, 1.8 ], [ 2, 1 ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1940b1192cab2195f7a8c"), "locs" : [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 7.5, 1.8 ], [ 2, 5 ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a193f11192cab2195f7a8a"), "locs" : [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1.5, 1.8 ], [ 2, 1 ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a193f11192cab2195f7a8a"), "locs" : [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1.5, 1.8 ], [ 2, 1 ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1940b1192cab2195f7a8c"), "locs" : [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 7.5, 1.8 ], [ 2, 5 ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1940b1192cab2195f7a8c"), "locs" : [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 7.5, 1.8 ], [ 2, 5 ] ] }
Fetched 6 record(s) in 8ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Make new table - a 1-to-meny relation. So have your objects table, and second with a object_id and a lat/long. If a object has many locations it has many rows in this new table.

Then just search this new table as you would otherwise. (be that mysql or sphinx)

(You already have an answer for MongoDB :)